# Check if xml response has type="array" using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, xpath, nokogiri

Given the following xml which has been parsed into `@response` [using Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foos type="array">
  <foo>
    <id type="integer">1</id>
    <name>bar</name>
  </foo>
</foos>
```

Does an `xpath` exist such that `@response.xpath(xpath)` returns `array`?

Assume that this xpath must be reused across multiple documents where the naming of foo is inconsistent.

If an xpath is not the correct tool to solve this problem, does Nokogiri provide a method that is?

This xml is automatically generated by the rails framework, and the answer to this question is intended to be used to create an XML equivalent to [this Cucumber feature for JSON responses](https://github.com/telamon/cucumber-api-steps/blob/master/lib/cucumber/api_steps.rb#L79).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select the root node when its `type` attribute is `array` (regardless of the root element's name), then use this:

```
/*[@type='array']
```

For its children, use:

```
/*[@type='array']/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
if doc.root['type']=='array'
```

Here's a test case:

```
@response = <<ENDXML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foos type="array">
  <foo>
    <id type="integer">1</id>
    <name>bar</name>
  </foo>
</foos>
ENDXML

require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML(@response)
if doc.root['type']=='array'
  puts "It is!"
else
  puts "Nope"
end
```

Depending on your needs, you might want to:

```
case doc.root['type']
  when 'array'
    #...
  when 'string'
    #...
  else
    #...
end
```